# How do I prevent my submit button in android from giving me multiple scores when clicked multiple times?

Tags: java, android

Whenever I answer a question and hit the submit button, a score of 1 should show but on hitting submit button again, it keeps adding 1 to the score and more hits on the submit button keeps adding more 1 to the score. I actually don't want 1 to be added to the score every time the submit button is clicked. I do not want the score to be updated based on the number of times I hit the submit button.

package com.example.android.generalknowledge;

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    int baseScore = 0;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

    public void submitResult(View view) {
        RadioButton largestRailwayStation = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.largest_railway_station);
        boolean answerIsLargestRailwayStation = largestRailwayStation.isChecked();

        RadioButton insects = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.insects);
        boolean answerIsInsects = insects.isChecked();

        CheckBox physicsChemistry = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.physics_chemistry);
        boolean physicsChemistryIsAnswer = physicsChemistry.isChecked();


        CheckBox physiologyMedicine = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.physiology_medicine);
        boolean physiologyMedicineIsAnswer = physiologyMedicine.isChecked();


        CheckBox literature = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.literature);
        boolean literatureIsAnswer = literature.isChecked();


        CheckBox peaceEconomics = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.peace_economics);
        boolean peaceEconomicsIsAnswer = peaceEconomics.isChecked();


        RadioButton naziParty = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.nazi_party);
        boolean answerIsNaziParty = naziParty.isChecked();


        RadioButton allOfTheAbove = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.all_of_the_above);
        boolean answerIsAll = allOfTheAbove.isChecked();


        RadioButton filmFinance = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.film_finance);
        boolean answerIsFilmFinance = filmFinance.isChecked();

        EditText enterNameHere = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name_view);
        String name = enterNameHere.getText().toString();


        EditText enterAnswerHere = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.answer_here);
        String answer = enterAnswerHere.getText().toString();
        if (enterAnswerHere.getText().toString().equals("Africa")) {
            baseScore += 1 ;
        }


        int finalScore = calculateTotalScore(answerIsLargestRailwayStation, answerIsInsects, physicsChemistryIsAnswer,
                physiologyMedicineIsAnswer, literatureIsAnswer, peaceEconomicsIsAnswer, answerIsNaziParty, answerIsAll, answerIsFilmFinance);

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                name + " " + "\n" + "You have a Total Score of " + " " + finalScore + " " + "/10", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called when any of the radio buttons in question one is selected
     */

    public void onRadioButtonClickedOne(View view) {
        // Is the button now checked?
        boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

        // Check which radio button was clicked
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.largest_railway_station:
                if (checked)
                    // This is the correct answer
                    break;
            case R.id.highest_railway_station:
                if (checked)
                    // Wrong answer
                    break;
            case R.id.longest_railway_station:
                if (checked)
                    // Wrong answer
                    break;
            case R.id.none_of_the_above:
                if (checked)
                    //Wrong answer
                    break;
        }

    }

    /**
     * This method is called when any of the radio buttons in question two is selected
     */

    public void onRadioButtonClickedTwo(View view) {
        // Is the button now checked?
        boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

        // Check which radio button was clicked
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.behaviour_of_human_beings:
                if (checked)
                    // Wrong answer
                    break;
            case R.id.insects:
                if (checked)
                    // This is the correct answer
                    break;
            case R.id.origin_history:
                if (checked)
                    // Wrong answer
                    break;
            case R.id.rock_formation:
                if (checked)
                    // Wrong answer
                    break;
        }

    }

    /**
     * This method is called when the checkboxes for question three are clicked
     */

    public void onCheckboxThreeClicked(View view) {
        //Is the button now checked?
        boolean checked = ((CheckBox) view).isChecked();

        // Check which checkbox is clicked
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.physics_chemistry:
                if (checked)
                    // One of the Correct answers
                    break;
        }
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.physiology_medicine:
                if (checked)
                    // One of the Correct answers
                    break;
        }
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.literature:
                if (checked)
                    // One of the Correct answers
                    break;
        }
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.peace_economics:
                if (checked)
                    // One of the Correct answers
                    break;
        }
    }

    /**
     * This method is called when any of the radio buttons in question four is selected
     */

    public void onRadioButtonClickedFour(View view) {
        // Is the button now checked?
        boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

        // Check which radio button was clicked
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.labour_party:
                if (checked)
                    // Wrong answer
                    break;
            case R.id.nazi_party:
                if (checked)
                    // This is the correct answer
                    break;
            case R.id.leading_party:
                if (checked)
                    // Wrong answer
                    break;
            case R.id.democratic_party:
                if (checked)
                    // Wrong answer
                    break;
        }

    }

    /**
     * This method is called when any of the radio buttons in question six is selected
     */

    public void onRadioButtonClickedSix(View view) {
        // Is the button now checked?
        boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

        // Check which radio button was clicked
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.develop_telescope:
                if (checked)
                    // Wrong answer
                    break;
            case R.id.discovered_jupiter:
                if (checked)
                    // Wrong answer
                    break;
            case R.id.movement_of_pendulum:
                if (checked)
                    // Wrong answer
                    break;
            case R.id.all_of_the_above:
                if (checked)
                    // This is the correct answer
                    break;
        }

    }

    /**
     * This method is called when any of the radio buttons in question seven is selected
     */

    public void onRadioButtonClickedSeven(View view) {
        // Is the button now checked?
        boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

        // Check which radio button was clicked
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.foreign_finance:
                if (checked)
                    // Wrong answer
                    break;
            case R.id.film_finance:
                if (checked)
                    // This is the correct answer
                    break;
            case R.id.federation_football:
                if (checked)
                    // Wrong answer
                    break;
            case R.id.none:
                if (checked)
                    // Wrong answer
                    break;
        }

    }


    private int calculateTotalScore(boolean questionOneAnswer, boolean questionTwoAnswer, boolean questionThreeAnswer1,
                                    boolean questionThreeAnswer2, boolean questionThreeAnswer3, boolean questionThreeAnswer4,
                                    boolean questionFourAnswer, boolean questionSixAnswer, boolean questionSevenAnswer) {

        if (questionOneAnswer) {
            baseScore += 1 ;
        }

        if (questionTwoAnswer) {
            baseScore += 1 ;
        }

        if (questionThreeAnswer1) {
            baseScore += 1 ;
        }

        if (questionThreeAnswer2) {
            baseScore += 1 ;
        }

        if (questionThreeAnswer3) {
            baseScore += 1 ;
        }

        if (questionThreeAnswer4) {
            baseScore += 1 ;
        }

        if (questionFourAnswer) {
            baseScore += 1 ;
        }

        if (questionSixAnswer) {
            baseScore += 1 ;
        }

        if (questionSevenAnswer) {
            baseScore += 1 ;
        }

       // EditText enterAnswerHere = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.answer_here);
       // String answer = enterAnswerHere.getText().toString();
       // {
        //    if (answer == "Africa") {
        //        baseScore = baseScore + 1;
        //    }
       // }
        return baseScore;
    }
}
```

Comment: Disable the button when the score has been increased.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can achieve by 2 ways,

- You can diable the button by button.setEnable(false); once user click for for time
- In your case if you don't have button object so you can use one global boolean and make that as false default and once user click for first time do the process and make that boolean as true, from next time check if the boolean is true just return it.

private boolean mIsSubmited = false;

```
        public void submitResult(View view) {
            if(mIsSubmited) {
                return;
            }
            mIsSubmited = true;
            RadioButton largestRailwayStation = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.largest_railway_station);
            // Remaining code..
        }
```

Comment: This worked so well Muthukrishnan Rajendran. Much appreciated!

Comment: If my answer helped you, you can make this as answer and if you liked it you can upvote ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the submit button once it is clicked. For eg:

```
onclick() {
   submitbutton.setEnabled(false);
}
```

Prevent user to click on submit again and again.

You can enable it back using:

```
submitbutton.setEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a Boolean globally and set it to false at first.
then on button click you can turn its value to true.
on the button click you can check if its false then only to increase the score.

Answer (score 0):

You can use handler for this may be there is better solution then this.

```
Handler mHandler=new Handler();
```

//now in your click listener

```
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mRunnable);//
        mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 500);

        Runnable mRunnable  =new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //calculate it
        }
    };
```

//Wait for half sec before calculating the result if user clicked before then  stop runnable from calcualting and again go for calculation.
Hope it helps.